# Passing arrays, pointers to int in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm new to C for numerical analysis after many years of working with Matlab.  I have a function that constructs an array and I need to get it back to main().  I had the usual trouble with arrays vs. pointers, and by fiddling figured out how to do this.  But the fiddling left me with a conceptual question based on the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void array_set(int y_out[2][2]);
void int_set_wrong(int  y);
void int_set_right(int *y);


int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int y_array[2][2]={{0,0},{0,0}};
    int y_int_1 = 0;
    int y_int_2 = 0;

    array_set(y_array);
    int_set_wrong(  y_int_1 );
    int_set_right( &y_int_2 );

    printf("\nValue array: %d \n",y_array[0][0]);
    printf("Value int wrong: %d \n",y_int_1);
    printf("Value int right: %d \n",y_int_2);

    return 0;
}

void array_set(int y_out[2][2]){

    y_out[0][0] = 10;
    y_out[1][0] = 20;
    y_out[0][1] = 1;
    y_out[1][1] = 2;
}

void int_set_wrong(int y){

    y = 10;

}

void int_set_right(int * y){

    *y = 10;

}
```

The snippet above returns:
Value array: 10
Value int wrong: 0
Value int right: 10

My question is in a few parts,

first, why does the function 'array_set' work?  I would expect it to fail in the same way that 'int_set_wrong' did.

How are ints and int arrays treated differently in passing?

Furthermore, in the case of 'int_set_wrong', is there a local version of y?

If so, why is there not a local version of y_out in case of setting the array?

Thanks for the help.  As an aside, if there is anything that will cause problems with my implementation of array_set, please chime in.

--Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `int_set_right()` you passed the address of the variable `y_int_2` (which you declared and defined in `main()`) through the operator `&`.

```
int_set_right( &y_int_2 );
```

Since the function had access to the actual variable `y_int_2` through the pointer `y` (set to the value of the address of `y_int_2` from `&y_int_2`), you assigned `y_int_2` the value `10` when you assigned `*y = 10`.

You can read `*y = 10` as:

> the value of the variable whose
>   address is stored in `y` is now set to
>   10

*But* for `y_int_1`, you merely passed the *value*. So a temporary variable was created when you called `int_set_wrong()` which was initialized with the **value** of `y_int_1`. So all you did was change the value of the temporary of the *local* variable (local to `int_set_wrong()`).

This is why the `y_int_1` declared in `main()` is not affected by `int_set_wrong()`.

`array_set` works because you passed the address of `y_array` to the function through the `y_out` variable (which is a pointer like `y` in `int_set_right`).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are passed using pointers rather than the entire array being copied by value on the stack. Your two dimensional array makes explaining this tricky, but consider a one dimensional version:

```
void f(int x[]){
    x[0] = 1;
    x[1] = 2;
}
```

You could equivalently write this as:

```
void f(int *x){
    x[0] = 1;
    x[1] = 2;
}
```

These two declarations are identical, but I'm sure you can see that modifications made in the the second version are propagated back to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

The function array_set works because when you pass an array into a function, you are really passing a pointer. Then, inside the function, you are de-referencing the array using "y_out[0][0] = 10" etc. When you use array notation, it automatically de-references the array pointer so you are able to set the values within the array.

Ints are completely different from int arrays. An array can be treated in almost every case as a pointer, in this case a pointer to int. An int is an actual numerical value. Therefore, when you pass an int into you're int_set_wrong function, it is copied (that's just what C/C++ does), and you are setting a local variable y, not the int you passed in.

You're third question is answered in the first paragraph as well. Hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works because in C the inner most `[]` in function arguments (and only there!) is equivalent to a pointer argument. Your declaration is equivalent to

```
void array_set(int (*y_out)[2]){
..
}
```

That is `y_out` is a pointer to `int[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You've created 3 functions.

```
array_set(y_array);
```

Prior to this you have created an array of numbers with the line.

```
int y_array[2][2]={{0,0},{0,0}};
```

In C when you declare an array you created a pointer in your code with the name `y_array` the array is stored somewhere in the memory and the pointer is pointing is holding the position of the location.

So essentially its a normal pointer with a big amount of memory allocated after it.

When you pass the array to save memory and time C by default passes the pointer.

```
void int_set_wrong(int  y);
```

When you pass an `int` it copies the value to a local variable as a result, you don't hold any address to that variable outside that function.

When you pass the reference of an `int` you supply the function with the address of your `int` variable. As a result, the function can make changes there.

As the first and third call is sharing the location of the main variable you can see the change from the main. For the second one there is no sharing of address. So the function creates its own variable which cannot be accessed from outside.