# 2 ways of initializing a linked list, do they equal?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
}ListNode;

void init(ListNode **head){
    (*head) = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    (*head)->next = 0;
}

ListNode* another_init(){
    ListNode *head = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    return head;
}
```

I have some problems:

1.in function init,why should I put a second rank pointer ?

2.Is function init the same with another_init ?

Comment: Well, for a start, `another_init` misses out assigning `0` to `next`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing arrays, pointers to int in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916716/passing-arrays-pointers-to-int-in-c)

Comment: This: ^^ because in C, arguments are passed by value ("copied").

Answer (score 1):

another_init is not "the same as" init. It doesn't set the *next*-pointer to 0. From malloc(3): *malloc()  allocates  size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  The memory is not cleared.*

Answer (score 0):

**2.Is function init the same with another_init ?**

In case you use `malloc` they are not equal If you use `calloc` ,they will be equal.

**1.in function init,why should I put a second rank pointer ?**

If you insist on malloc . You should set the `next` to `0` .

Or you will face bugs sometime. Thinks this:

Maybe you have a print_link function:

```
void print_link(struct node * head)
{
    node * now = head;
    while(now != NULL)
    {
        print_some_data_you_want;
        now = now->next;
    }
}
```

And if you just call this function after  use the second init function. You never know what will happened.